# accessing couchdb stored view using django

Tags: django, couchdb

I'm using the Django framework with Couchdb, building on the example from here:
[intro to using couchdb with django](http://lethain.com/entry/2008/aug/18/an-introduction-to-using-couchdb-with-django/)

I've had no trouble using ad-hoc couchdb views, but when I replace it with a stored view I'm getting back no results.

This, for example, worked:

```
def index(request):
    docs = SERVER['docs']
    all_pages = "function(d) { if ( (d.title.length>0) && (d.type=='otherpage') ) emit(d.title,d); }"
    pages = [ x for x in docs.query(all_pages) ]
    all_blogposts = "function(d) { if ( (d.title.length>0) && (d.type=='blogpost') ) emit([d.date,d.title],d); }"
    blogposts = [ x for x in docs.query(all_blogposts) ]
    return render_to_response('couch_docs/index.html',{'pages':pages,'blogposts':blogposts})
```

However, this did not:

```
def index(request):
    docs = SERVER['docs']
    all_pages = docs.view('_view/example/all_pages')   
    pages = all_pages.rows()
    all_blogposts = "function(d) { if ( (d.title.length>0) && (d.type=='blogpost') ) emit([d.date,d.title],d); }"
    blogposts = [ x for x in docs.query(all_blogposts) ]
    return render_to_response('couch_docs/index.html',{'pages':pages,'blogposts':blogposts})
```

When I go to the Futon screen and select the example/all_pages view, it returns several documents.  However, when I try to use this from within Django it returns no results.  It also returns nothing when I do it at the python command line.  It would appear that I am not defining all_pages correctly?  If I print it out it's the following:

```
<ViewResults <PermanentView '_view/example/all_pages'> {}>
```

So, yeah, it's empty.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  When I select the "all_pages" view under "example" in Futon, it comes back with results with no problem.  Any help is appreciated.

p.s. so I also tried this tutorial:[Snakes on a Couch!](http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/7179/1/)

I have the same problem, namely that while I can connect to Couch, start up Futon, create databases, documents, and design documents (at the python command line) and then see them (including in Futon), I cannot get results back from a permanent view.  I found again that I could run the view from inside Futon (the exact same one created at the python command line), and get results back, but when trying to use the view from python I got no results back.

Since this was doing character for character what they were doing in the tutorial, I am thinking it probably means there's not a problem with my code, but rather with my software setup.  Any ideas on what piece is most likely to have the problem, or how to track it down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here's what worked:

```
def index(request):
docs = SERVER['docs']
pages = [ x for x in docs.view("_design/example/_view/all_pages") ]
all_blogposts = "function(d) { if ( (d.title.length>0) && (d.type=='blogpost') ) emit([d.date,d.title],d); }"
blogposts = [ x for x in docs.query(all_blogposts) ]
return render_to_response('couch_docs/index.html',{'pages':pages,'blogposts':blogposts})
```

I'm not totally sure why that worked, since the examples and documentation I read seemed to indicate that I didn't need the _design and/or the _view in there.  But, you know, it works, so I'm going with it.  Perhaps it's some version difference in couchdb-python?

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple different reasons this could be happening.  Keep in mind that Futon adds a couple extra parameters automatically, try loading the view directly:

curl http://localhost:5984/docs/_design/example/_view/all_pages

If that does load than it's an issue with your Python code.  In python-couchdb the syntax would be:

couchdb.Server('http://localhost:5984')['docs'].view('example/all_pages')

If that works, than it's an issue with how your interacting with your couchdb library.

Incidentally, [x for x in anything] is the same as just using the list constructor, e.g. list(anything).

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Still something odd, though.  When I try:http://localhost:5984/docs/_design/example/_view/all_pages, I get results.  When I try (in the views.py file): pages = couchdb.Server('http://127.0.0.1:5984')['docs'].view('example/all_pages'), I get back <ViewResults <PermanentView '_view/example/all_pages'> {}>, the same empty thing.  Any ideas on how to track down the difference between the two results?